# Can you populate a range in ClosedXML (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, closedxml

I wanted to see if you can populate a range all at once from an array [when using closedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com) instead of populating a single cell at a time. Also, if it is possible to set a range from an array, would that be faster than looping through cell by cell and populating each cell?

Comment: They have some comprehensive examples in the [documentation section](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation). They might not have the exact solution to your question but look around and I'm sure you'll get your answer just by looking at the examples over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to [insert data as a DataTable](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Adding%20DataTable%20as%20Worksheet&referringTitle=Documentation) and see if it will speed up document creation. But as I can see in source code, there is no optimisation possible whatsoever against single cell population (but I can be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
cell.Value = yourArray;
```

See the section "Inserting Data/Tables" of the [Documentation](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation).